# Can I mix a 2GB and a 4GB stick of ram in the Dell inspiron n5010?

Tags: memory, compatibility, laptop

I have a Dell inspriron n5010 and I want to upgrade the RAM.

It currently has 3GB of RAM. It has a 2GB stick and a 1 GB stick.

I was thinking that I would replace the 1 GB stick with [this](http://www.staples.com/Kingston-ValueRAM-4GB-1-x-4GB-DDR3-204-Pin-SO-DIMM-DDR3/product_376285) stick that I ordered. I am pretty sure it has all of the right specs with 204 pins, SO-DIMM DDR3, and 1333 speed rating. It says that the RAM is universal. I am not sure if the 9-9-9 timing is right.

So my question is will it work(I know it won't go into dual channel mode or whatever it is called), and if so do I need to put certain sticks into certain slots? By the way I know that the max ram in the Dell inspiron n5010a is 8GB and I would be under that with 6GB(4GB and a 2GB stick).

Comment: Which one is it.. actually I am planning to upgrade it ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That stick of memory will work just fine for your system. The [specifications](ftp://ftp.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_laptop/esuprt_inspiron_laptop/inspiron-15-intel-n5010_setup%20guide_en-us.pdf) for your laptop say that it accepts 1GB, 2GB, and 4GB DDR3 SODIMMs in the 1067Mhz and 1333Mhz varieties.

Comment: So the difference in voltage doesn't matter? One has 1.5 and other has 1.35.

Answer (score 0):

The Crucial System Scanner (http://www.crucial.com/uk/systemscanner/) will tell you exactly what will fit in there. (It will also suggest some for you to buy, but you don't have to buy from Crucial.)

Comment: I used the scanner and all of the RAM that it told me I should get had 1.35V and the one that I ordered had 1.5V. Is that a concern?

Answer (score 0):

If the Mhz are the same and both sticks are the same technology (like DDR, DDR2, DDR3) then it will work.